# How to send response to client when files is too large with Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm using NodeJs [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to upload files. I need to send response back to a client when file user tries to upload is too large. The problem is that `onFileSizeLimit` only has file as argument and I dont know how to send response to client. What I need to do is basically soomething like below:

```
app.use('/users/gyms/upload-logo', multer({
    // other settings here then:
    onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {
        // but res (response) object is not existing here
        res.json({
            message: "Upload failed",
            status: MARankings.Enums.Status.FILE_TOO_LARGE
            // status: -6
        });
    }
});
```

`res` object dosent exists in there however and I'm wondering what is the best way to send some sort of response to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it's good to remember that Multer itself is just a (middleware) function that Express calls to get its response.

You could perhaps try with this:

```
app.use('/users/gyms/upload-logo', function(req, res, next) {

    var handler = multer({

        // other settings here then:
        onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {

            // res does exist here now :)
            res.json({
                message: "Upload failed",
                status: MARankings.Enums.Status.FILE_TOO_LARGE
                // status: -6
            });

        }

    });

    handler(req, res, next);

});
```

This basically aliases multer to handler, passes `req, res, next` from the Express callback, and means you get access to the `req, res, next` variables from within Multer's configuration.

I haven't tested this but I think the theory is sound!

Comment: you sir are a genious! BTW would you happen to know any good urls that cover middleware and sort of tricks you show in your example? Couldn't find anything interesting apart from basic express usage

Comment: but it seems like multer still uploads the first part of the file up to the file size limit, replacing what is there with a partial file?

Comment: @PixMach, I got the same problem. I just delete that partial file.  Not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
app.use('/users/gyms/upload-logo', multer({
    // other settings here then:
    onFileSizeLimit: function (file) {
        // but res (response) object is not existing here
        file.error = {
            message: "Upload failed",
            status: MARankings.Enums.Status.FILE_TOO_LARGE
            // status: -6
        };
    }, onFileUploadComplete: function (file, req, res) {
        if (file.error){
            res.send(file.error);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the one marked as answer above. If using onFileUploadComplete to return a json, and onFileSizeLimit to return a json at the same time, you will get an error from node: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue which has not been resolved by the author of multer yet. This github [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/72) has quite a lot of discussion about it:

Answer (score 1):

There is one work around which I have used in my current project

File: make-middleware.js
change "function done(err)" at end of this function

Replace 
Line 52: `onFinished(req, function () { next(err) })`

With:
Line 52: `onFinished(req, function () { if(err.code == 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') { req.fileSizeError = 1; next() } else next(err) })`

And in app file you can change the code to

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('upload'), function (req, res, next) {
    if(typeof req.fileSizeError != "undefined") {
        res.send({"error":"File too large"});// to display filesize error
    } else {
        res.send({"file":req.file}); // when file uploaded successfully
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The multer file object actually contains a property indicating whether the file exceeded the size limit. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#multer-file-object

To accept only one file with a maximum size of 2 MB and the name "data" I did something like this:

```
app.use(multer({
    dest: "./uploads/",
    putSingleFilesInArray: true, // see https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#putsinglefilesinarray
    limits: {
        files: 1,
        fileSize: 2097152 // 2 MB
    }
}));
app.post("/foo", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.files.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
        // 400 Bad Request
        return response.status(400).end();
    }
    var file = request.files.data[0];
    if (file.truncated) {
        // 413 Request Entity Too Large
        console.log("Request aborted.");
        return response.status(413).end();
    }
    // do stuff with file
});
```